# Let $x$ be a positive real number. Inequality problem with $\pi$ and $x$ terms.

Tags: number-theory, inequality, pi

Let $x$ be a positive real number. Then

(A) $ x^{2} + \pi^{2} + x^{2\pi}> x\pi+ (\pi+x)x^{\pi} $

(B) $ x^{\pi} + \pi^{x}> x^{2\pi}+ \pi^{2x} $

(C) $ \pi x +(\pi+x)x^{\pi}>x^2 + \pi^2 + x^{2\pi} $

(D) none of the above.

I've tried using AM GM inequality. But not been able to solve. It became more cumbersome.
And I know it can be solved using substitution (x=1). But I want to know the process, intuition to such problems Help??

Comment: The title you have chosen for your question is quite not descriptive of the question. **Please** try to pick a better one.

Comment: @Macavity Please can you help? Or tag someone you know of?

Comment: You asked the question **7 minutes** ago. If you are in a hurry, then this site is not for you.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I just joined today!! I'm not getting how this forum works? I deleted because my question got too many negative upvotes. As I was not clear with my question. So I deleted. Is this forum really for people to help and know and grow? Or to be censored ruthlessly?

Comment: If you browse a bit, you will see that yes, it is an excellent place to help and to learn. If you only have 10 minutes to do so, though, it is not the correct place.

Comment: As I posted in the other thread before you deleted it, one general approach to such problems is to move everything to the left hand side of the inequality so it becomes a problem of showing $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$, and then show $f(0)\geq0$ and $f'(x)>0$ for $x>0$.  I'm not sure how well that will work for these examples, but in terms of a general strategy to solve such problems, you should put this one in your toolbox.

Comment: **Please** do not ask the same question twice. I closed the other one (which you asked only some 10 minutes before this one!) as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Thanks for suggesting. But the maxima minima approach I tried. But it's not making sense here too much. The terms are getting way too jumbled.

Comment: Looks much better now. +1 for that.

Comment: @barakmanos Thank You. Learning. :)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I'm not getting you. You have problem with me deleting my question. So I undeleted? So what should I do? Is this a Maths forum or some cult? Please cut me some slack.

Comment: @NS You need to show your attempt at solving the problem and patience to benefit from this forum.  Questions which show no effort and demand immediate responses are frowned upon by the community here, which more or less regulates things.  Also if someone is not active already in a post, tagging them does not help - they never get to know you referred to them.

Comment: @Macavity I know. I really apologise sir. But I wish more people were like you. I didnt know Math Jax few hours back.Thanks to your kind patience I learnt fast. And also I asked you such silly questions regarding AM GM. You didnt lose your cool or downvoted me. You are really an epitome of a learned man sir. May god bless you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show something is not true, a counter example is enough.  Substituting $x=1$ shows (B) and (C) are incorrect.  What is left is to check (A).  For this, some creative AM-GM works, add the following three AM-GMs:

$$\frac{x^2}2+\frac{\pi^2}2 \ge \pi x \tag{1}$$
$$\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^{2\pi}}2 \ge x\cdot x^\pi \tag{2}$$
$$\frac{\pi^2}2+\frac{x^{2\pi}}2 \ge \pi\cdot x^\pi \tag{3}$$

Equality is possible iff $x=\pi = x^\pi$ which is never, so the inequality is strict.  Hence (A) is correct.

Comment: Thanks Sir. Your answers are so easy to understand. Really I'm grateful to have someone like you answer my doubts.

Comment: @NS glad to help.  Others are as well, you just need to understand the rhythm of this community to benefit well.